# Call a native android app from ionic app

Tags: android, plugins, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I’m developing an app that will be called by an android native app. I also have to call them. For doing this I found [this plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme).

They will call my app (and expect me to call theirs) following this code:

```
String packageName = “com.android.app”;
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
if (intent == null) {
   // The app is not installed
   intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setData(Uri.parse(“market://details?id=” + packageName));
}
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra(“param”, “aaaaa”);
startActivity(intent);
```

I don’t get if the plugin will work to open my app when they do this (and their app will open also).

I look for a way of using intends in ionic but I found nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it will help someone how I resolved it.

To open another android app I use the [com.lampa.startapp](https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp). The code for doing it it's:

```
var sApp = startApp.set({
    "package": "packageName" //The packageName of the app I want to open
}, {
    //extras I want to add
    "myParams" : "aaaaa"
});
sApp.start();
```

To work with intents (the ones that open my app) I use the [cordova-plugin-intent](https://github.com/napolitano/cordova-plugin-intent) with the following code:

```
//To get the intent and extras when the app it's open for the first time
window.plugins.intent.getCordovaIntent (function (intent) {
    intenthandler(intent);
});

//To get the intent and extras if the app is running in the background
window.plugins.intent.setNewIntentHandler (function (intent) {
    intenthandler(intent);
});

//To handle the params
var intenthandler = function (intent) {
      if (intent && intent.extras && intent.extras.myParams) {
        //Do something
      }
};
```

That's all!