# Cordova Mobile app and Native iOS Mobile app communication

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am looking for communication between **iOS native app** with **cordova app** in the form of response.
I have read some of the stack overflow questions and answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937424/hybrid-ios-web-and-native-app-events-communication) but not getting exact solution.

So please help me to find out exact way to find solution, Is there any plugin available in cordova which gives me interface to communication between native and hybrid.

For the android I got the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165813/call-a-native-android-app-from-ionic-app) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218893/get-extras-in-cordova-app).

Comment: Why not use a real time socket server that both apps connect to ??

Comment: Actually both application are installed in same device and then needs to communcation

Comment: That doesn't go against it. If both apps are running, they can send and receive data via that central point. You could also store data that wasn't delivered on the server side and fetch it when one app start.

Comment: i need to call events vice versa from both

Comment: Again, doesn't go against it.

Comment: I means need to trigger the application from cordova to ios or ios to cordova

Comment: Yup, you can do it that way. You can emit a msg from Cordova app to the iOS app and the other way around. Upon receiving the msg, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: can you please give me any refrence for that ?

Comment: Maybe read about sockets? Maybe this is a good start http://socket.io/